# How do I access the internal storage from a test project?

Tags: android, testing

I have a instrumentation test that uses test data.  I have included this test data as an asset file in the test project, and it works well.

I would like to speed up re-running the test with different test data by just pushing the test data file to the internal storage of the test app and then let the test read the test data from the internal storage if it exists.

However, I am unable to access the internal storage from the test app.  I am using a subclass of `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`, and all calls to `getContext().getFilesDir()` return `null`.

Are test apps not able to access the internal storage?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try calling `getFilesDir()` on a `Context` from one of your `TestCases` (e.g., `AndroidTestCase`).

Comment: The test cases are `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` instances and they only offer to get the `Context` via the `Instrumentation` class, so that would probably give me the same `Context` as in the instrumentation test runner.  More importantly, I generate test instances based on the test data, so I need to access the test data before all the tests are instantiated.

Comment: Use `getActivity()` in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` to get at the `Activity` object, and from there use `getFilesDir()`. "More importantly, I generate test instances based on the test data, so I need to access the test data before all the tests are instantiated." -- then I suspect you're screwed and will have to hard-wire in a path.

Comment: Hey! did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Roboguice with your tests, make sure you implement the constructor of your application class like this:

```
public MyApplication(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    this();
    attachBaseContext(instrumentation.getTargetContext());

    //this does not work:
    //attachBaseContext(instrumentation.getContext());
}
```